# What is the oldest Ubuntu version available for the rPi4?

Tags: ubuntu

The Big Blue Button (BBB) application requires 4GB of RAM & is supported on 16.04:  BBB [will be supported on 18.04 in the near future](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigbluebutton-setup/X0fiVEe-s7s). I would like to test BBB on the rpi4.

Is there any instances of installing Ubuntu that pre-dates 19.10?

Comment: Why do you need the **oldest** version? Why not the current stable one?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be fixated on installing Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi.

The simple fact is there is **NO** supported version of Ubuntu that runs on **ANY** model Pi.

Canonical does not seem to be interested! Ask on Ubuntu sites why - it seems to be due to Canonical's fixation with open-source software (although this is my opinion).

There are [Ubuntu Server images by Canonical](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) which you can install on the Pi but these are **NOT supported**.

[Ubuntu MATE for the Raspberry Pi Model B 2, 3 and 3+](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) - 16.04 worked on Pi3 - but is **unsupported** and has no updates since Wimpy started to work for Canonical. My experience with the later versions has been lacklustre.  18.04 is **still in Beta!!**

There are a number of hackers who have made 16.04 and later versions work on various Pi models (I have done so myself) and I am sure that could be done on a Pi4, **BUT** it is a lot of work, and frankly there seems to be nothing that can't be done on Raspbian.

The later semi official releases are heavy on resources and light on performance!

If you REALLY want Ubuntu forget the Pi and try some other processor.